# External monitor using USB-VGA display adapter in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, multiple-monitors, vga

Here are my laptop specifications

[image]

I want to add an external monitor using USB-VGA adapter like this:

[image: Image 2]

For this I have installed the USB-VGA driver and also updated my video driver for windows. Bus somehow it does not detect when I connect it with USB-VGA adapter On the other hand, if I connect it with my HDMI connector it works perfectly.

Please guide me where I am making a mistake?

Comment: Why you need a USB-VGA connector? Doesn't your laptop have VGA port? Or you are connecting to two *external* monitors?

Comment: Well both. My laptop does not have VGA port and also I want to connect 2 monitors. So I am using 1 monitor with HDMI cable and for other I need to use USB-VGA adapter

Comment: Try connecting monitor 1 and 2 with the usb-vga adapter. Can they both be recognized?

Comment: Both monitors are recognized if I use HDMI cable with both. But none of them works when I use them with USB-VGA adapter. How can I connect monitor 1 and 2 with this cable I think its meaningless